# Angular not calling link function from directive

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I am working with Leadtools on a project. Their support has assisted me in porting their document viewer over to angular.js. Their sample is just an index.html page with a call to two directives: list and documentviewer. I've taken that code and modified it so that the code in the index.html is now in a partial and the directives I left alone. Here is the directive code they gave me:

```
JBenchApp.directive("documentviewer", function () {
    return {        
        //templateUrl: "views/docviewer.html" //"<div id='documentviewerdiv'></div>",
        template: ' <div id="container"> ' +
        '<div id="top-panel">' +
        '<label for="interactiveSelect">Interactive mode:</label>' +
        '<select id="interactiveSelect"></select>' +
        '</div>' +
        '<div>' +
        '   <div id="left-panel"></div>' +
        '  <div id="middle-panel"></div>' +
        '<div id="right-panel">For bookmarks</div>' +
        '</div>' +
        '</div>',
    restrict: 'E',
        link: link
    };

});

JBenchApp.directive('list', function () {
    return {
        templateUrl: 'partials/list.html'
    };
});

function link(scope, element, attrs) {

  //This code handles displaying the documents. I've removed it as it isn't relevant to the question
};
```

This link function is never called. It works in the demo, but not here. Here is the code for the partial:

```
<div class="row">

   <div class="col-sm-3">

        <list>
            {{ listItems }}
        </list>
   </div>
   <div class="col-sm-8">
      <section  ng-app="JBenchApp"> 
            <documentviewer></documentviewer>
      </section>        
   </div>

</div>
```

The documentviewer directive is called and the HTML template part of it works fine, but the link function just never runs. Any ideas?

Comment: This works just fine with me, see [example](https://jsfiddle.net/o51dce6k/1/)

Comment: @sniels I see that you have declared your directive differently. I also changed my directive so that link now looks like this: `link: function(){ alert('link fired'); }` Nothing fires

Comment: Seems to work with me, maybe there's something else going on in your project that we don't know about. See https://jsfiddle.net/o51dce6k/2/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer to this was instructive. Another developer had previously attempted to migrate the vendor's sample application into our application. He left a directive and a link function in place that were named identical to the one I was trying to use. Taking out the second directive and second link function accomplished the task. Thanks for all the help everyone.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe it's a typo you've only made here in stackoverflow, but you are missing a character:

```
<div class="col-sm-8"> <!-- Missing ">" -->
```

Comment: thanks, but that was just a typo here. I am fixing it now.

Answer (score 1):

> but the link function just never runs

**Maybe**, by putting your link funciton in the glocal scope, it is being rewritten (?).

Try to move your link funciton inside your directive definition.

Comment: I am probably going to give this a try, but the one thing that isn't making sense to me is that it works in their demo and the code is the same.